# Автовоспроизведение кастомных аудиометок на точках маршрута

Tags: веб-сайт, pwa

Делаю PWA **БЕЗ кода**, поэтому сорри если терминология не та. Мне нужно

1. Либо в Яндекс.Навигаторе

- Создать кастомные точки маршрута с кастомными аудиометками и краткой инфо по каждой точке. Это реально? С помощью чего?
- При движении по маршруту по этим точкам, в Навигаторе автоматически воспроизводить аудиометки к тем точкам что подъезжаю + показывать на экране инфо этих точек. Это реально? С помощью чего?
- Обменитваться по API данными этих своих точек + результатов поездок. Где в документации такой раздел?

2. Либо в моем приложении,

- запускать Яндекс.Навигатор в iFrame с теми же фичами из п.1. Это реально? С помощью чего?
- перенаправлять юзера на Навигатор  с теми же фичами из п.1.
  Это реально? С помощью чего?

Спасибо.